# Is there a way of alter first iteration of for loop for adding strings?

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop, concatenation

I currently have a for loop, and I am looking for a quick and elegant method to remove the plus sign `+` from the first "adding" of the loop, so the results is not `+example+input+string` but rather `example+input+string` preferably without the need of rewriting the loop much.

```
String inpputString = "example input string";
String outputString= "";
    
String[] stringPieces= mainString.split(" ");
    
for (String strTemp : stringPieces){
    outputString = outputString + "+" + strTemp;
}
```

Comment: `outputString = String.join("+", stringPieces);`

Comment: @shmosel, thanks! Didn't realize that option existed

Comment: @shmosel - write it up as an answer, it's better than mine

Comment: Why don't you just `replace(" ", "+")`?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the observation that you don't want a separator the first time - use an empty separator the first time!

```
String sep = "";
for (String strTemp : stringPieces) {
    outputString += sep + strTemp;
    sep = "+";
}
```

Comment: Elegant solution thanks!

Comment: A StringBuilder would maybe be a better use.   Either of @shmosel solutions would be better IMO.

Comment: @ScaryWombat - in this case, I agree that the join/replace solutions are better.  But the technique I used has useful applicability if you can't reduce your loop to a simple call on an existing String method, so I'll let the answer stand.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would proffer the solution using `String.join()` proposed by *@shmosel* in the comment.

Here is another way of achieving this with Stream API:

```
String outputString = 
    Arrays.stream(stringPieces).collect(Collectors.joining("+"));
```